# Install .deb package only if version is higher

Tags: apt, dpkg, deb

Is it possible to tell `dpkg` to only install a `.deb` if the new package version is higher than what's already installed on the system?

Example:

I have `htop` version 3.0.5 installed and I attempt to install `3.0.4` with `dpkg -i htop-3.0.4-ubuntu.deb`. The behavior I want is for `dpkg` to abort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from `dpkg --help`:

```
Options:
  -G|--refuse-downgrade      Skip packages with earlier version than installed.
```